# Phalcon Zircote/Swagger-php security error

Tags: swagger, phalcon, swagger-ui, php-7.2, swagger-php

I'm trying to use `Swagger-php` to create a documentation for API in application I'm working on. I'm want to secure it using JWT so putted a SecurityScheme in my ControllerBase:

```
/** 
 * @SWG\SecurityScheme(
 *     securityDefinition="Bearer",
 *     bearerFormat="JWT",
 *     type="apiKey",
 *     name="Authorization",
 *     in="header"
 * )
 */
```

And then in my controller I wanted to use it

```
/**
 * @SWG\Get(
 *      path="/test",
 *      @SWG\Response(
 *          response="200",
 *          description="Returns test data"
 *      ),
 *     security={{"Bearer":{}}}
 * )
 */
```

It is loading correctly on my Swagger UI but when I try to execute the request I got an error in response:

> Syntax error, unexpected token }, near to '}}

It looks like the correct annotations for Swagger are incorrect for PHP Interpreter. I can change it to

```
security={{"Bearer":{''}}}
```

And then the request is working but when I reload the Swagger UI the request doesn't show up there.

Can anyone help me, please?

UPDATE: I was wrong to think that this is a problem with PHP Interpreter. Problem occurs while using Phalcon Annotations. Here is the whole error returned by server.

> Syntax error, unexpected token }, near to '}} ) ' in
>   /var/www/api/api/app/modules/user/controllers/UserController.php on
>   line 21
>
> ```
> 0 [internal function]:
> Phalcon\Annotations\Reader->parse('Api\Modules\Use...')
> 1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Annotations\Adapter->get('Api\Modules\Use...')
> 2 /var/www/api/api/app/library/ApiManager/ApiAnnotation.php(54): Phalcon\Annotations\Adapter->getMethod('Api\Modules\Use...',
> 'getAllUsersActi...')
> 3 /var/www/api/api/app/library/ApiManager/ApiAnnotation.php(41): Api\Library\ApiManager\ApiAnnotation->getFromActiveAction()
> 4 /var/www/api/api/app/library/AuthGuard/AuthGuard.php(23): Api\Library\ApiManager\ApiAnnotation->__construct()
> 5 /var/www/api/api/app/controllers/ControllerBase.php(37): Api\Library\AuthGuard\AuthGuard->__construct()
> 6 [internal function]: Api\Controllers\ControllerBase->initialize()
> 7 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
> 8 /var/www/api/api/public/index.php(54): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
> 9 {main}
> ```

Comment: You need to remove `bearerFormat="JWT",`, it's only used in OpenAPI 3.0 but not in 2.0.

Comment: "I got an error in response: Syntax error, unexpected token }, near to '}}" - is this error returned by your server?

Comment: @Helen I've updated the question. Yes, this all is returned by my server.

Comment: What's on line 21 in UserController.php?

Comment: @Helen
 `     
*        security={{"Bearer":{}}} 
`  
Looks like this is something that Phalcon Annotations cannot deal with